# (Python)Список в вложенный словарь

Tags: python, list, dict, генераторы

Имеется словарь и список :

```
dict_cost = {'A': {},
                'B': {},
                'C': {},
                'D': {},
   }
tariff = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16']
```

Нужно сделать цикл либо генератор для вот такого результата:

```
dict_cost = {'A': {1 : 1, 2 : 2, 3 : 3, 4 : 4},
   'B': {1 : 5, 2 : 6, 3 : 7, 4 : 8},
   'C': {1 : 9, 2 : 10, 3 : 11, 4 : 12},
   'D': {1 : 13, 2 : 14, 3 : 15, 4 : 16},
   }
```

Вот мой код:

```
Branch = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    
    dict_cost = {'A': {},
                'B': {},
                'C': {},
                'D': {},
   }
    
    tariff = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16']
        
    dict_cost = {Branch[n]: tariff[n] for n in range(len(Branch))}
```

Но генератор выдает вот такое:

```
{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '4'}
```

Помогите с этим пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте извратимся

```
{l:dict(zip(range(1,5), tariff[i:i+5])) for i, l in zip(range(0, len(tariff)+1, 4), Branch)}
```

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
n = (len(tariff) - 1) // len(dict_cost) + 1
result_dict = {d: {i:int(t) for i,t in enumerate(tariff[i*n:i*n+n],1)} for i,d in enumerate(dict_cost)}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @GrAnd, кажется вот здесь `int(t):int(t)` у вас не совсем то что нужно автору вопроса

Comment: Согласен. Спасибо за то, что указали на это.

Answer (score 1):

еще вариант, немного длинновато, но зато читабельно:

```
from itertools import islice

t = iter(tariff)
for d in dict_cost:
    dict_cost[d] = dict(enumerate(islice(t,4),1))
```

результат:

```
print(dict_cost)
'''
{'A': {1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4'}, 
 'B': {1: '5', 2: '6', 3: '7', 4: '8'}, 
 'C': {1: '9', 2: '10', 3: '11', 4: '12'}, 
 'D': {1: '13', 2: '14', 3: '15', 4: '16'}}
```